Automate rule that moves e-mail sent to a public folder to a subfolder of the public folder
I created a rule in Outlook:
Mails from "example@adress.net" sent to the publicfolder "Finance" shall be moved to the sub-(public)folder "Finance 2".
I've tried it and it works like I want.
Problem: Outlook doesn't check if there is new mail in a public folder, so the rule can't work automatically.
Is there a way to schedule the rule like a Windows task? E.g. "Run this rule every 10 Minute" with a macro or similar?

Reference Outlook's Public folder in VBA, Public folders in vba, Run a code every half an hour

Outlook rule run in all the folders and "consider implementing the required functionality in VBA without rules involved"

No, server side rules won't work on PF store folders - they only work on mailboxes.
Client side rules only run when Outlook is running, they cannot be scheduled.
